# Java regexp multiple exclusion conjonction

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm currently coding my own Java JSON parser, based on the grammar defined on the site  https://www.json.org

In particular, an **'escape'** object is defined by any element of the list : '"', '\', '/', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't' or 'u hex hex hex hex' (where *hex* refers to any hex digit)

While a **'character'** is defined by any character except : any ASCII control character (0x00-0x1F), '"', '\' or '\' + **escape**

Then I've tried to defined the **escape** regexp with : ["\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4} which seems to work correctly.

`String ESCAPE_REGEXP="[\"\\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}";`

However I cannot find how to compute the regexp of a **character**. I tried to define it as a negation form of the non-character disjunction : ^([\u0000-\u001f] | [\"\\] | \\("+ESCAPE_REGEX+"))";

But it does not seem to work. I also wonder whether it is possible to compute a conjunction (logical AND) of multiple negations regexp ?

Thanks for your helps :)